# woocommerce hooks for registering new user and updating user

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need a function to execute **add_new_user_details** within my Woocommerce site but am struggling applying the relevant hook.  I need to execute it after a new user places an order and adds billing info etc.

When I test the below by completing an order, it doesn't seem to doing anything. I have tried using 'woocommerce_order_status_processing' and 'user_register' hooks.

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_complete', 'add_new_user_details' );
    function add_new_user_details($user_id){
          $user_id = get_current_user_id();

          echo $user_id;

    }
```

Comment: Just trying to understand this better, since the function call of  `add_xero_contact_id` is being made inside `add_new_user_xero_contact_id` it implies that the action is being called. Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: I am sorry, I had written this question incorrectly.  I have amended the above, so hopefully this makes more sense.  Thank you for pointing this out for me.

Comment: Try using the `woocommerce_thankyou` hook, it gets fired when the order is confirmed by the user. The hook passes `$order_id` using which you can grab the details of the user who placed the order.

Answer (score 1):

you could try the woocommerce_checkout_process hook which, I think, fires after the checkout form is posted. http://oik-plugins.eu/woocommerce-a2z/oik_hook/woocommerce_checkout_process/